# Could not find commons-codec.jar in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've installed **Android Studio 3.0**, once I open an app which ran perfectly on **Android Studio 2.3.3**, now when when I try building the app in **Android Studio 3.0** it shows,

> Error:Could not find commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar

Help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Solution is simple. Just follow these steps*

**1.** Download commons-codec-1.6.jar file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6)

**2.** Place this file in the following location

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\m2repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar

***DONE***

Comment: Any help?? I am getting error like this>> Gradle sync failed: Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.0.1).
   Searched in the following locations:
   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.0.1/shared-26.0.1.jar
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 376ms)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you missed adding maven repo to your build.gradle file.

```
   buildscript {
repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
}
```

For more info on updating gradle follow [Migrating to Gradle Plugin 3](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)